# Mockery mock and spy called 0 times on custom class in controller

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mockery

I'm having difficulty with the spy and mock in Laravel 7 test when I test for MyCustomClass.

I have tried both mock before running $this->get and spy after $this->get. Both with the same error message (*below).

When running debug in the controller the $myCustomClass is still the MyCustomClass and not the mocked object.

**MyCustomClass**

```
class MyCustomClass
{
 public function execute()
 {
   return 'hello';
 }
```

**MyController**

```
class MyController
{
 public function show()
 {
   $myCustomClass = new MyCustomClass();

   $data = $myCustomClass->execute();

   return $data;
 }
```

```
private $mySpy;

public function testAMethod()
    {
        $spy = $this->spy(MyCustomClass::class); 

        $response = $this->get('/my/path');

        $spy->shouldHaveReceived('execute');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

**Error**

```
Method execute(<Any Arguments>) from Mockery_2_App_MyCustomClass should be called
 at least 1 times but called 0 times.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are instantiating `MyCustomClass` yourself with the `new` keyword.

In order for Laravel to be able to swap out the real class with the spy you have to use the [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/container).

Something like this:

```
class MyController
{
    public function show(MyCustomClass $myCustomClass)
    {
        return $myCustomClass->execute();
    }
}
```